# RNG implementation without unsigned int

Tags: random, pytorch

I need implement random number generator by myself in Pytorch, and in my knowledge, all kinds of RNG need unsigned int in the implementation. However PyTorch only supports uint8 tensors but not uint32, uint64. Is there an RNG implementation that uses only int instead of uint?

Comment: What do you mean by "int instead of uint"?  Can you use 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit signed integers in PyTorch?  Can you use 16-bit unsigned integers in PyTorch?

Comment: Pytorch only support uint8, int8, int16, int32, int64. My question how do i only use such type to implement a high quality RNG.